# glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff being sought in Content/fonts in Release mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.Net MVC5 application, started from a sample application.
When I deploy this, in release mode, I get

HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://SERVER/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

That's not where the font is. If I go to https://SERVER/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 I can download the file just fine, so it's not an IIS mimeType issue.

Edit: Locally reproducible by removing debug="true" from my Web.config

I cannot find any configuration in my application, no BundleConfig, nothing, that specifies where to find the fonts. How do I fix this in release mode?

EDIT: Here are my BundleConfig

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customjs").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/Custom/btn-number-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Custom/input-number-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Custom/PriceList/tax-calculation-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/charts").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/Chart.js"));

        // Bundle CSS for public part of the site
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Public/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        // Bundle CSS for dashboard and other actions, when user is logged in
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Dashboard/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css", 
                  "~/Content/dashboard.css"));
    }
}
```

EDIT: and the font section of bootstrap.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: I think this is an issue with Bundling or `src` in `@font-face` of css. Share your `BundleConfig.cs` and font section from your `bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of the relative paths in your css file when they get bundled result in invalid locations for your fonts (and any other `url` content in your css). You need to use `CssRewriteUrlTransform` to update these paths while the bundle is created.

```
// Bundle CSS for public part of the site
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Public/css")
       .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Comment: Hmm, where does it expect to find the files with the CSS rewrite URL transform applied? You'll need to add this parameter to all the CSS bundles.

Comment: I did. I added it to all .css bundles. In Debug mode, icons are visible, in Release they are not. I'm at my wits end, because as far as I can see there is no difference between Debug and Release, when it comes to my BundleConfig or scripts...

Comment: Yes, but where are does the CSS expect the files to be after the bundling is applied with this parameter? What is the 404 error say?

Comment: HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https : / /SERVER/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Comment: I found a resolution, but I don't understand why it works. Posting it as an answer, but if someone can explain *why*, then I'm willing to accept a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but if I update my BundleConfig as follows, the problem is resolved. Note, I have removed the "Content" part of the path, making the path one level less deep.

```
        // Bundle CSS for public part of the site
        // Note: Don't change to deeper path, like Content/Public/css
        // This will result in broken relative paths in .css in Release mode
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Public/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        // Bundle CSS for dashboard and other actions, when user is logged in
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Dashboard/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/dashboard.css"));
```

If anyone has an explanation for why Debug can handle an extra level in the bundle and Release can't, I'm willing to accept their answer as the true answer. In the meantime, this has resolved by problem :)

Comment: Debug simply skips the optimization, so no bundling is performed in Debug mode. Hence it works in debug.